# Append path to python program

Tags: python, path, tree, python-import

My program has the next structure:

```
|---main.py
|---home
      |----read.csv
      |----importer.py
```

main.py has the next code:

```
from home import importer as imp
imp.load()
```

importer.py has the next code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys


def load():
    arch = pd.read_csv("read.csv")
    print arch


if __name__ == '__main__':
    load()
```

and read.csv is any csv, it is for example

```
h,k
3,4
5,6
```

When I run importer.py, it runs ok, and that's because read.csv is in the current path.

But when I try to run main.py, it throws an exception, because it can't find read.csv.
It's because read.csv is not in the current path.

I need it works in both modes, and the solution would be to append the home path to the python main program.

I tried to do this
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "home"))
but it did'nt work.

Any idea?

Comment: you have to use absolute paths not relative paths. i suggest having `load` take in a path parameter and passing in a absolute path every time.

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` in your home directory?

Comment: Yes, I have       __init__.py       in home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
def load():
    filedir, _ = os.path.split(__file__)
    arch = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(filedir, 'read.csv'))
    print arch
```

Comment: I think then that you have to specify the full path. It works but I'd liked to be able to add this path so you always have access to every file in home.